# How can I use @property in class method? ios7

Tags: class, methods, properties, ios7, instance

I got MyWebClass class method that sent web request and It gets response, I need to get http header, so I use

```
@property NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
```

and in MyWebClass class method I need to use

```
    NSDictionary *headerDictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
```

to get header, but I can not, how can I solve it? I not really want to change that class method to instance method

that property is defined on MyWebClass.

Answer (score 0):

If that property is defined on your UIViewController, you could use:

```
NSDictionary *headerDictionary = [self.response allHeaderFields];
```

Since it's defined in your MyWebClass, you could do something like this (assuming it's a singleton):

```
MyWebClass *myWebClass = [MyWebClass sharedInstance];
NSDictionary *headerDictionary = [myWebClass.response allHeaderFields];
```

Because "`response`" has a property defined in it's public .h interface file, you can access it from any place in your app.  Of course, response has to be non-nil in order for you to be able to get all header fields from it.

Comment: that property is defined on MyWebClass

Comment: and is MyWebClass a singleton or is it a property or an ivar (instance variable)?

Comment: MyWebClass now is not singleton but it will be later, it is class that makes request and got responds, it has 1 class method with string: NSDictionary *headerDictionary = [response allHeaderFields]; and 1 property: @property NSHTTPURLResponse *response;